# Trying to get single line output from awk getline + variable

Tags: awk, concatenation, getline

File 1 has tab delimited content:

```
09/11/1983  so and so <bob@bob.com>     content of my imp. msg
09/12/1983  yo yo yoooo <politics@me.com>   content of my imp. msg
```

File 2 has space separated content:

```
bob@bob.com 7155
politics@me.com 2666
```

I am using the following awk command to make a new file that adds the numbers from each line in file 2 as new tab separated data at the end of each line in file 1.

```
awk 'BEGIN {ORS="\t"} {getline f1 <"c:\\file1.tsv" ; print f1 $2}' < "c:\\file2.tsv" > "c:\\file3.tsv"
```

However, the output adds the numbers as new lines, as such:

```
09/11/1983  so and so <bob@bob.com> content of my imp. msg  
7155
09/12/1983  yo yo yoooo <politics@me.com>   content of my imp. msg  
2666
```

I have read about awk ORS and have tried many combinations of suggested solutions, but have been unable to get the output to look like this:

```
09/11/1983  so and so <bob@bob.com> content of my imp. msg  7155
09/12/1983  yo yo yoooo <politics@me.com>   content of my imp. msg  2666
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance in a solution.

Comment: Are you on Windows or Unix? If you're on Windows then I'm surprised that using single quotes around the script is working but if you're on Unix then I'm surprised that using `c:\\...` to reference files is working.

Comment: If windows files, try `dos2unix file1 file2` and rerun. Else `getline f1 <"c:\\file1.tsv" ; sub("/n","",f1);print f1 $2}'` might help. Sorry, don't have time to test. Good luck.

Comment: I am on Windows10 but using cygwin64 as an emulator.  I ran `awk '{getline f1 <"c:\\file1.tsv" ; sub("/n","",f1) ; print f1 $2}' < "c:\\file2.tsv" > "c:\\file3` but the output continues to add the numbers from file 2 as new lines in file 3.  Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: First running the dos2unix command on the original data files and then running the awk command resolves the issue!  Ah, thank you!

Comment: Arg, Typed my advice late last night. Try it without the `sub()..` thing as it should have been `sub("\n","",f1)`, but once you've done `dos2unix` it may not matter. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

since you're not matching corresponding lines, just paste

```
$ paste file1 <(cut -d' ' -f2 file2)

09/11/1983  so and so <bob@bob.com>     content of my imp. msg  7155
09/12/1983  yo yo yoooo <politics@me.com>   content of my imp. msg      2666
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me.  Running this command placed the data from file 2 in column 1 of file1 rather than at the end as a new column.  I will play with it a bit, thank you.